# c++ template: boost::mpl::transform with template template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, boost-mpl

Now that my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23119046/c-template-allocator-for-template-container/23119097) has a solution, more questions arise.

I want to use the `wrap_into_container` meta-function with boost::mpl::transform, e.g.:

```
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <boost/fusion/include/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/mpl.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/transform.hpp>

namespace container
{
    template <typename T> struct vector { typedef std::vector<T> type; };
    template <typename T> struct list   { typedef std::list<T> type; };
}

template<typename T, template <typename> class Container>
struct wrap_into_container
{
    typedef typename Container<T>::type type;
};

int main()
{
    namespace fusion = boost::fusion;
    namespace mpl = boost::mpl;

    typedef fusion::vector<int, float, int> vec_type;
    typedef mpl::transform< vec_type, wrap_into_container<mpl::_1, container::vector> >::type wrapped_vec_type;

    wrapped_vec_type w;
    return w.size();
}
```

[Link to coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bb91c91c9a0db238)

But it seems like I cannot pass a template template parameter into mpl::transform ...

How can I solve this? Please provide a C++03 solution, since I cannot use C++11.

Comment: `wrap_into_container<mpl::_1, container::vector>` is a plain type whose `::type` is `std::vector<mpl::_1>`, right? So what template template parameter are you talking about?

Comment: The second template argument of wrap_into_container is a template template parameter. So the correct wording is "I cannot pass a Lambda Expression into mpl::transform which depends on a template template parameter"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `boost::mpl`, higher order functions are written by passing a fixed type with an internal `apply` template member (known as a [metafunction class](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/metafunction-class.html)), rather than through the use of template-template parameters. [Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5044b66e11ec78f5).

```
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <boost/fusion/include/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/mpl.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/transform.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace container
{
    struct vector {
        template<typename T> struct apply {
            typedef std::vector<T> type;
        };
    };
    struct list   {
        template <typename T> struct apply {
            typedef std::list<T> type;
        };
    };
}

template<typename T, typename ContainerMaker>
struct wrap_into_container
{
    typedef typename ContainerMaker::template apply<T>::type type;   
};

int main()
{
    namespace fusion = boost::fusion;
    namespace mpl = boost::mpl;

    typedef fusion::vector<int, float, int> vec_type;
    typedef mpl::transform<
        vec_type,
        wrap_into_container<mpl::_1, container::vector>
    >::type wrapped_vec_type;

    wrapped_vec_type w;
    std::cout << size(w) << "\n";
    return size(w);

}
```

Comment: Thanks! Now that you named it, I also found the corresponding boost documentation at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/mpl/doc/tutorial/higher-order.html

Answer (score 1):

I don't know `boost::mpl`, so I can only speculate from what I've seen in the documentation.

I think what you need is

```
template<template <typename> class Container>
struct wrap_into_container
{
    template<typename T>
    struct map
    {
        typedef typename Container<T>::type type;
    };
};
```

Followed by

```
typedef wrap_into_container<container::vector>::template map<mpl::_1> fun;
typedef transform<vec_type, fun>::type wrapped_vec_type;
```

In this case, `fun` is a class of the form `C<mpl::_1>` where `C` is a class template, and whose `::type` is `std::vector<mpl::_1>`. I think this is what `mpl::transform` expects for its type map.

My only test is with my own version of `transform`, which works with template template arguments instead of placeholders for the type map. Check [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fb331df3ac519faa), where `transform` is defined using C++11 but the remaining part is C++03. In this example, I am only using

```
wrap_into_container<container::vector>::template map
```

as a template template argument to my `transform`, without the placeholder `<mpl::_1>`.

I hope this helps.

Comment: This works as well, but the accepted answer shows the "boost::mpl"-way of doing it.

Comment: @m.s. Ok nice to know. For a moment I got scared and deleted my answer, but looking again at the documentation I was sure it was valid so I undeleted it :-)